# codeception curl error 7 connection refused

Tags: curl, laravel, acceptance-testing, codeception, guzzle

I am trying to run codeception on my Laravel app. Using Homestead running on Vagrant VM. I made a simple acceptance test and get `[GuzzleHttp\Exception\AdapterException] cURL error 7: Failed to connect to site.dev port 8000: Connection refused`

All I've done is installed codeception and made a simple test. `$I->amOnPage('/')` is the first step and that's where it fails.

Not sure what information is needed to debug this. I can connect to site.dev:8000 just fine.

my acceptance.suite.yml

```
 class_name: AcceptanceTester
 modules:
    enabled:
       - PhpBrowser
       - AcceptanceHelper
    config:
       PhpBrowser:
          url: 'http://site.dev:8000'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to remove the port from the url. Now it works just fine.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: That is the answer. I removed the port and it works now.

Comment: My apologies.  I mistagged.  I meant to say that you should mark your answer as accepted so that we know you don't need help anymore.  Good luck!

Comment: Won't let me for two more days. I will though.

Answer (score 2):

You Need to use a specify driver, like Webdriver or PHPBrowser.

I used to use Webdriver, with phantom js.

Edit your question with the configuration of what suit are you using (accepcante, functional, unit or a custom). Is a file called by the suite configuration name, acceptance.yaml, functional.yaml.

You should have enabled Webdriver on this configuration file. (Or PHPBRowser, or Selenium).

And should start it with a 8000 port to work property.

phantomjs --web-driver=8000

Edit:
There are modules: there are 2 enable. PhpBrowser i can't get working to myself so I change to Webdriver. Webdriver work with phantom js like i said before.

Install Phantomjs 1.9.* on your machine for headless testing, configure acceptance.yaml to this:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
   enabled: [WebDriver]
config:
   WebDriver:
     url: 'http://YOUR_MAIN_URL/'
     browser: phantomjs
     capabilities:
         webStorageEnabled: true
```

Then should start working.

Then for a full guide, use [WebDriver Docs](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver)

Comment: How do you install phantomjs. I found https://github.com/jakoch/phantomjs-installer as a way to do it with composer. any recommendations?

Comment: It just says Webdriver is not configured when I use that code.

Comment: I used apt-get for ubuntu 12.04. Did you have apt-get enabled? Try to download and install from global http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: I got it working with PHP Browser. I read when I vagrant up I would have to redownload it since it isn't in composer or anything like that.